# Canvas Animation: Pixels per Second with requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, canvas, pixel, requestanimationframe, milliseconds

I have a function to move images by the canvas.

The run subfunction runs on each frame and when it returns true ends.

The problem is that the speed of movement depends on how many fps you have.

I would like to be able to put a variable that is pixels per second, so the image will always move at the same speed regardless of how many fps you have.

```
this.MoveImage = function(opts){
    var image = opts.image;
    var x1 = opts.x1;
    var y1 = opts.y1;
    var x2 = opts.x2;
    var y2 = opts.y2;
    var angle = Math.atan2(y2-y1, x2-x1);
    var speed = opts.speed;
    var xDirection = null;
    var yDirection = null;

    if(x1 < x2)      xDirection = "positive";
    else if(x1 > x2) xDirection = "negative";
    if(y1 < y2)      yDirection = "positive";
    else if(y1 > y2) yDirection = "negative";

    this.run = function(){
        x1 += speed*Math.cos(angle);
        y1 += speed*Math.sin(angle);

        context.drawImage(image, x1, y1);

        if(compare(x1, x2, xDirection) && compare(y1, y2, yDirection)){
            return true;
        }
    }

    function compare(n1, n2, direction){
        if(n1 >= n2 && direction == "positive")         return true;
        else if(n1 <= n2 && direction == "negative")    return true;
        else if(n1 == n2 && direction == null)          return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `requestAnimationFrame` callback is sent a `timestamp`  using this you could create what's called a Delta Time,.. this would then be consistent no matter what FPS / or even CPU power the computer is using.

Comment: I have the delta, but what I need to know are the pixels that have to move the image in each frame, with a pixel per second variable.

Comment: var getPixelsToMove = function(pixelsPerSecond){
  var pixels = (delta * pixelsPerSecond) / 1000;

  return pixels;
 }

Comment: I think I can do it

Comment: Yes.  Multiplying by the delta time is how it's normally done.  Big game engines like Unreal etc, do exactly that.